# Heapify function: how do I find last interior node?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement a bottom-up binary heap construction for a Priority Queue.  So far I've put all my values into an ArrayList in any order, and now I want to find the last interior node's element# and then run my BubbleDown() function on it, then iterate through each interior node in the heap.

How do I find the element# of the last interior node?  Here's how the table looks, with (N = # of elements in heap, LIN# = element # of Last Interior Node):

```
    N   LIN#
    2   1
    3   1
    4   3
    5   3
    6   3
    7   3
    8   7
    9   7
    10  7
    11  7
    12  7
    13  7
    14  7
    15  7
    16  15
    etc etc
```

Comment: Show code. What is last interior node

Comment: You cannot run heapify to heapify all elements. You need to run it after every insert into your Priority Queue. In other words one run of heapify will not make your collection a priority queue.

Comment: Okay maybe I'm using the wrong term.  This is building a heap from scratch.  Top node is element 1, followed by 2 3, then 45 67, then 89 1011 1213 1415, where each child is either element 2n or 2n+1 of the parent.  By last interior node I mean the last element that is not a leaf.  So as an example, if N=15, then the leaves are 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15, and the last interior node is 7.